# Getting updates in every blockchain append

Tags: callback, bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

I am working on an art project which desplays bitcoin transactions graphically.
Thus i need some way of getting an update when a transaction is filed in the blockchain.

Is there any way to accomplish this without copying the whole blockchain, since i do not need any precise information about the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to get all the transactions that are happening, then you have to parse each new block that comes in. You have to look into the RPC Calls to get each individual block.

If you just want to watch certain addresses for transactions you can look into walletnotify of the bitcoind node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when the only Detail i need is the amount, which Linux tool would be the best to get the last block?